# Popup should show once per visit, shows every time instead

Tags: javascript

I want my popup to show only once per visit. What am I doing wrong? It shows every time I refresh the browser.

This is what I've got.

```
<body onload="myFunction()">
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div id="ac-wrapper" style='display:none'>
    <div id="popup">
      <center>
        <h3>DISCLAIMER</h3>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="I AGREE" onClick="PopUp('hide')" id="button" />
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    var cookie = localStorage.getItem('myPopup');
    if (!cookie) {
      function PopUp(hideOrshow) {
        if (hideOrshow == 'hide') document.getElementById('ac-wrapper').style.display = "none";
        else document.getElementById('ac-wrapper').removeAttribute('style');
      }
      window.onload = function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
          PopUp('show');
        }, 1000);
      }
      localStorage.setItem('myPopup', 'true');
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: It's important to have a title that communicates the nature of your problem so people can find problems they can help with. I've adapted your explanation into one so this doesn't get lost or closed.

Comment: Ohhh I'm brand new here. Sorry. Will keep it in mind. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Your code works correctly as is. You do have an error because there's no `myFunction()` defined, but that should have no impact on the rest of your code.

Comment: Claudia - See @CrazyTrain's comment above: The indentation (and my dodgy eyes) fooled me, but your code should be doing what you expect (other than an error from the `myFunction` thing): http://jsbin.com/bazidulimu/edit?html,js It's best not to put function declarations within a control flow block in loose mode, but the above would work reliably cross-browser anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Move the If(!cookie) inside window.onload function

```
<body >
            <!-- Modal -->
        <div id="ac-wrapper" style='display:none'>
                <div id="popup">
                        <center>
                                 <h3>DISCLAIMER</h3>
                                 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="I AGREE" onClick="PopUp('hide')" id="button" />
                        </center>
                </div>
        </div>

        <script>
            var cookie = localStorage.getItem('myPopup');
            function PopUp(hideOrshow) {
                if (hideOrshow == 'hide') document.getElementById('ac-wrapper').style.display = "none";
                else document.getElementById('ac-wrapper').removeAttribute('style');
            }
            window.onload = function () {
                if(!cookie){
                        setTimeout(function() {
                  PopUp('show');
                }, 1000);        }

            }
            localStorage.setItem('myPopup','true');
        </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: *"Move the If(!cookie) inside window.onload function"* Why?

Comment: Its not good practice to write functions inside conditions, but still it will work.